# Are null events possible?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

From [Probability and Random Processes by Geoffrey Grimmett and David Stirzaker](https://www.amazon.in/Probability-Random-Processes-Geoffrey-Grimmett/dp/0198572220)-

> An event $A$ is called *null* if $\Bbb{P}(A)=0$. Null events should not be confused with the impossible event $\emptyset$. Null events are happening all around us, even though they have zero probability; after all, what is the chance that a dart strikes any given point of the target at which it is thrown? That is, the impossible event is null, but null events need not be impossible.

Doesn't a probability of $0$ mean that the event cannot happen just like a probability of $1$ means that the event has to happen?

Comment: For something continuous, like the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, any particular value has probability $0$, but of course it is possible to get a particular value.

Comment: Note that the term "null event" hasn't got a universally accepted meaning. Some writers, as here, say it means "probability $0$".  Others say it means "an event that can not occur".  Context should determine which meaning is intended.

Comment: *"Doesn't a probability of 0 mean that the event cannot happen just like a probability of 1 means that the event has to happen?"* No, neither of those things is true. :-D